# Raster graphics file format for fast loading in browsers

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, inkscape

I have many raster graphics in various file formats. They are either JPEG or PNG but generated by different applications with different compression levels etc. These files are embedded base64 encoded (by `inkscape`) in SVG's for display in a web application. It is crucial that browsers can load and render the graphics rapidly since this process otherwise disturbs javascript animations I implemented. By rapid loading I don't refer to the file transfer here but the mere process of their displaying. 
What options do I have to improve the raster graphics? Apparently some of the graphics blow up drastically in size (up to a factor of 10) when they are embedded in the files. Does this happen if the original files are compressed or is there any other reason?

Comment: Why are you embedding the rasterized images in SVGs?

Comment: I don't see what's obvious about the sentence that begins Obviously...

Comment: @Kaiido No. I mean that I tried it. For some files their embedding with creates very large output. I do this btw by converting PDF files which contain the images on the command line. An inkscape option to reference external images does not seem to exist there. The images and the PDF files are sometimes much smaller.